# «Значит» – обособленное или необособленное слово?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

1. Ставишь блогеру дизлайк – значит(,) показываешь ему свой к нему дисреспект.

А здесь?

2. Если ставишь блогеру дизлайк, значит(,) показываешь ему свой к нему дисреспект.

А здесь?

3. Если ставишь блогеру дизлайк, то(,) значит(,) показываешь ему свой к нему дисреспект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всех случаях ставится запятая, это **вводное слово**:

(1) Ставишь блогеру дизлайк – **значит,** показываешь ему свой к нему дисреспект.

(2) Если ставишь блогеру дизлайк, **значит,** показываешь ему свой к нему дисреспект.

(3) Если ставишь блогеру дизлайк, **то, значит,** показываешь ему свой к нему дисреспект.

Разница **в грамматике предложений.**

В первом случае это ***БСП***, "***значит***" является **структурным элементом**, уточняющим отношения между двумя простыми предложениями при отсутствии союза. (В школьной практике говорится, что вводное слово используется в значении союза.)

Во втором случае это ***СПП***, для связи используется дойной союз  ***ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ***.  Вводное слово является второй частью союза и обособляется.

Во третьем случае используется двойной союз ***ЕСЛИ...ТО***, а вводное слово –  дополнительный структурный элемент. Этот вариант встречается не часто.

**[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)**

Comment: Sharon? What about it?

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что в первом предложении запятая не нужна:

***Ставишь блогеру дизлайк – значит показываешь ему свой к нему дисреспект***.

*Значит* — **связка**.

В остальном Sharon права.

Comment: Максим, а связка бывает межу подлежащим и сказуемым: 

Поставить блогеру дизлайк – значит показать ему свой к нему дисреспект.

Comment: @Sharon Об этом и речь. Ставишь дизлайк = показываешь дисреспект. _Ставишь_ — подлежащее, _показываешь_ — сказуемое.

Comment: Это два односоставных предложения,  а нам нужен инфинитив.

Comment: А обязательно должен быть инфинитив? Тут с первого взгляда видно связку. Если два глагола не в начальной форме не могут составлять составлять грамматическую основу, то дайте ссылку на источник о том, что только два инфинитива могут образовать грамматическую основу, или сами докажите.

Comment: Понять — значит простить.  Пункт 3.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо, понятно.

Comment: А можете на другой вопрос ответить? Почему в предложении: _Мой дачный участок, шириной 200 метров, — это рай_ — вы поставили эти запятые? Здесь уточняющий или присоединительный оборот или что?